# python for loop to find and print names from blizzard api behaving erratically

Tags: python, for-loop

I am working on a script to find and print the ilvls of my guild in python through the blizzard api. I realize that my code is ugly/horrible/not optimized. This is my first python project and I am learning as I go.

The problem I am having is that when I run the script, it gives me erratic results when printing the names of characters in my guild. Some it will print multiple times, others it will work as intended and just print once. I am more than likely going about the process entirely wrong, but what I have come up with has worked until now.

Here is the code:

```
def guild_list(glink):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(glink) as url:
         gSource = url.read()
         gSourceDecoded = gSource.decode(encoding='UTF-8')
         gSource2 = str.replace(gSourceDecoded,"\"",' ')
         #finds total number of "characters"
         stringo = gSource2.split()
         nameCount = str(stringo.count('character'))
         gFirstSpace = gSource2.find('character')
    nameC = 0
    while nameC != int(nameCount):
        nextName = gSource2.find('character', gFirstSpace + 1)
        spaceBeforeName = gSource2.find(' ', nextName + 18)
        spaceAfterName = gSource2.find(' ', spaceBeforeName + 1)
        nameLen = spaceAfterName - spaceBeforeName
        cName = gSource2[spaceBeforeName + 1:spaceBeforeName + nameLen]
        gFirstSpace = gFirstSpace + nameC
        print(spaceBeforeName,'space before character name.')
        print(spaceAfterName,'space after character name.')
        nameC = nameC + 1
        print(cName)
        print(nameC,'number of instance \"character\" found.')

guild_list('http://us.battle.net/api/wow/guild/mugthol/license%20and%20registration?fields=members')
```

The results I get start out repeating the same name a few times. Then gradually start listing each name only once. This is where I am confused.

Results:

```
708 space before character name.
717 space after character name.
Euphoria
1 number of "character" found.
708 space before character name.
717 space after character name.
Euphoria
2 number of "character" found.
708 space before character name.
717 space after character name.
...
255 number of "character" found.
32740 space before character name.
32748 space after character name.
Bawbity
256 number of "character" found.
32997 space before character name.
33009 space after character name.
Kilikinilei
```

Thank you for the help, and again I apologize if my code is horrible to read. I am learning as I go.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using string operations to parse that data. It is in JSON format so just use the builtin [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library to parse it into native Python dicts.

Answer (score 2):

```
import json
import requests

def guild_info(guild_name, fields="members"):
    url = "http://us.battle.net/api/wow/guild/{guild_name}/license%20and%20registration?fields={fields}".format(guild_name=guild_name, fields=fields)
    pg = requests.get(url).content
    return json.loads(pg)

info = guild_info("mugthol")
```

gets you a dict containing the data. You can then use it like

```
for member in info["members"]:
    char = member["character"]
    print("{name:<15} Level {level} ".format(**char))
```

which gets you

```
Introvert       Level 88 
Euphoria        Level 86 
Timid           Level 90 
Intricacy       Level 87 
Obscurity       Level 90 
Silhouette      Level 40 
Ragingfupa      Level 87 
Enragedfupa     Level 90 
Ragingticks     Level 90 
# ... etc
```